# For given $n,m \in \Bbb N$ such that ${n}^9=19m+r$, how to find ${r}^n(mod 19)$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Written with [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/).
>   Let $m,n \in \Bbb N$ and ${n}^9 = 19m + r$, then the only possible values for $r \  modulo \  19$ are
>   (a) Only 0
>   (b) Only 0, 1,-1
>   (c) Only 1,-1
>   (d) None of the above

Well, I do notice that what we have to do is check the values of ${n}^9 \ modulo \ 19$ for n=1,..,18. We can even reduce some to smaller versions like $$10=5*2$$ however when it comes to primes, we can't use brute force. So, what method is actually expected in this problem?

Source - Tata Institute of Fundamental Research, Graduate School Admissions 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $19$ is prime, [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem) gives us that, if $19 \nmid r$, $r^2 \equiv n^{18} \equiv 1 \bmod 19$ and since the two roots of $1$ are $\{-1,1\}$ we know that $r \equiv \{-1,0,1\} \bmod 19$